# Extract public/private key from PKCS12 file for later use in SSH-PK-Authentication

Tags: ssh, openssl, certificate, x509, pkcs#12

I want to extract the public and private key from my `PKCS#12` file for later use in SSH-Public-Key-Authentication.

Right now, I'm generating keys via ssh-keygen which I put into `.ssh/authorized_key`, respective somewhere on the client-side.

In future, I want to use the keys from a `PKCS#12` container, so I've to extract the public-key first from `PKCS#12` and then put them into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Is there any chance to get this working via `openssl`? Are the keys in `PKCS#12` compatible for ssh-public-key authentication?

Answer (score 345, accepted):

You can use following commands to extract public/private key from a PKCS#12 container:

- PKCS#1 Private key

  ```
  openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
  ```
- Certificates:

  ```
  openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out publicCert.pem
  ```

Comment: the commands work, but the Private key is exported as PKCS1 format and I need PKCS8... Is there any option I am missing to get this?  For example, it exports '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----' but I need '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----'

Comment: To do that you could try `openssl rsa -in privateKey.pem -out private.pem`

Comment: @edthethird: To get PKCS8, add the -nodes flag

Comment: To export without password, add `-passout pass:`. It expects the parameter to be in the form pass:mypassword.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27497899/206277

Comment: @ChristopherK. thanks! that was the good one for me. adding `-nodes` exports the key correctly

Comment: To get the CA certificate, use `openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -out caCert.pem`

Comment: This only exports the first certificate.

Answer (score 98):

This is possible with a bit of format conversion.

To extract the private key in a format openssh can use:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pkcs12.pfx -nocerts -nodes | openssl rsa > id_rsa
```

To convert the private key to a public key:

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout | ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -i -m PKCS8
```

To extract the public key in a format openssh can use:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in pkcs12.pfx -clcerts -nokeys | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -i -m PKCS8
```

Comment: Thank you! The first line was the one I needed. Just the key, unencrypted, so it can be installed via most CDNs automated systems.

Answer (score 21):

OpenSSH cannot use PKCS#12 files out of the box. As others suggested, you must extract the private key in PEM format which gets you from the land of OpenSSL to OpenSSH. Other solutions mentioned here don’t work for me. I use OS X 10.9 Mavericks (10.9.3 at the moment) with “prepackaged” utilities (OpenSSL 0.9.8y, OpenSSH 6.2p2).

First, extract a private key in PEM format which will be used directly by OpenSSH:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -clcerts -nodes -nocerts | openssl rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I strongly suggest to encrypt the private key with password:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -clcerts -nodes -nocerts | openssl rsa -passout 'pass:Passw0rd!' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Obviously, writing a plain-text password on command-line is not safe either, so you should delete the last command from history or just make sure it doesn’t get there. Different shells have different ways. You can prefix your command with space to prevent it from being saved to history in Bash and many other shells. Here is also how to delete the command from history in Bash:

```
history -d $(history | tail -n 2 | awk 'NR == 1 { print $1 }')
```

Alternatively, you can use different way to pass a private key password to OpenSSL - consult [OpenSSL documentation for pass phrase arguments](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS).

Then, create an OpenSSH public key which can be added to authorized_keys file:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: What's the `| openssl rsa` stuff for?

Comment: @Snekse it makes sure there's only private key in the output. In my case, it creates identity file (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) with some “cruft” like Bag Attributes without ` | openssl rsa`. I guess OpenSSH and other utilities which use identity file can handle that cruft (I haven’t tried), but I am simply used to provide only the necessary data and nothing more, especially if it's something around security.

Comment: This answer worked for me to get access to the PEM-format private key in the terminal, which I was able to copy/paste:

`openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -clcerts -nodes -nocerts`

Answer (score 11):

Solution 1:

**Extract P12 from jks**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore MyRootCA.jks -destkeystore MyRootCA.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

**Extract PEM from P12 and Edit file and pem from crt file**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MyRootCA.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out MyRootCA.crt
```

**Extract key from jks**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MyRootCA.p12 -nocerts -out encryptedPrivateKey.pem
openssl rsa -in encryptedPrivateKey.pem -out decryptedPrivateKey.key
```

Solution 2:

**Extract PEM and encryptedPrivateKey to txt file```**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in MyRootCA.p12 -out keys_out.txt
```

**Decrypt privateKey**

```
openssl rsa -in encryptedPrivateKey.key [-outform PEM] -out decryptedPrivateKey.key
```

Comment: When answering questions it helps to highlight what the commands are.  You can do that by adding three backquotes before and after the command so \`\`\`echo hello\`\`\` becomes ```echo hello```.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I noticed that my answer was just a poor duplicate of a well explained question on [https://unix.stackexchange.com/...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367220/how-to-export-ca-certificate-chain-from-pfx-in-pem-format-without-bag-attributes?rq=1) by [BryKKan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/160045/brykkan)

Here is an extract from it:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <filename.pfx> -nocerts -nodes | sed -ne '/-BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-/,/-END PRIVATE KEY-/p' > <clientcert.key>

openssl pkcs12 -in <filename.pfx> -clcerts -nokeys | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > <clientcert.cer>

openssl pkcs12 -in <filename.pfx> -cacerts -nokeys -chain | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > <cacerts.cer>
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is the correct command, I just want to add one additional thing, when extracting the key if you leave the PEM password(`"Enter PEM pass phrase:"`) blank then the complete key will not be extracted but only the `localKeyID` will be extracted. To get the complete key you must specify a PEM password whem running the following command.

Please note that when it comes to Import password, you can specify the actual password for `"Enter Import Password:"` or can leave this password blank:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

Comment: That should be a comment to accepted answer, not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know PKCS#12 is just a certificate/public/private key store. If you extracted a public key from PKCS#12 file, OpenSSH should be able to use it as long as it was extracted in **PEM** format. You probably already know that you also need a corresponding private key (also in **PEM**) in order to use it for ssh-public-key authentication.