# When I am trying to enable the push notifications in server side it shows error like these

Tags: ios, exception

**AppleServiceException**

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI
>   failed, see inner exception. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the certificate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your APNs certificate. Check if the certificate is valid. Ensure that you are using proper certificate for APNs (there are two types of certificate - 1. Development 2. Distribution).

Try looking at this SO question for more details.

- [iOS Push Notifications AuthenticationException for Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947135)