# Export a PKCS#12 file without an export password?

Tags: openssl, command, pkcs#12

I am generating exporting some pkcs#12 files for testing purposes. These files are not being used in production and only exist temporary during automated testing.

I am using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -out bundle.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile ca-cert.crt
```

Why is it insisting on an export password when I have included `-nodes`?

My OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` on Ubuntu Server 14.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In interactive mode, when it prompts for a password, just press enter and there will be no password set.

If you are want to automate that (for example as an ansible command), use the `-passout` argument. It expects the parameter to be in the form `pass:mypassword`. Since we want no password:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -out bundle.pfx -inkey mykey.key \
    -in certificate.crt -certfile ca-cert.crt \
    -passout pass:
```

Comment: This generates a file with an empty string as the password, which is not the same as no password. You still have to press enter on a password prompt, and this doesn't work on iOS devices because they won't let you push enter with an empty string.

Comment: I found this to not work in a CRON process either. Instead I just made up a temporary password and stored it in the script as a variable, as the script's purpose was only to transfer a Let's Encrypt certificate in P12 format to a 389-DS instance. (The P12 file was discarded immediately after.)

Comment: `-nodes` is not even a valid parameter when `-export` is being used, see man page. Hitting return twice sets an empty password, which is not the same as no password. `-passout pass:` also sets an empty password. My answer proves by looking at the code that it is not possible to create a PKCS#12 file with no password on command line, only when directly using libcrypto. @Nick is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Nick my openssl throws an error when I leave PEM pass empty, why?

Comment: Please see the [answer further down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497723/export-a-pkcs12-file-without-an-export-password#62863490) on how to create a pcks12 with **NO** password via openssl instead of an empty string password.

Answer (score 31):

**tl;dr** If you explicitly set the encryption algorithms both to `NONE` (the one for the key and the one for the cert), you will still have to provide a password but as no encryption is performed, it won't matter which password you provide as the password is simply ignored and the resulting file is not encrypted.

For a full command line sample, check out this reply: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62863490/7878845

### Very detailed answer:

`-nodes` means "don't encrypt private key" but in a PKCS#12 file, the certificates are encrypted as well, so even with `-nodes` you'd need an export password.

See documentation of `-descert` which says:

> Encrypt the certificate using triple DES; this may render the PKCS#12 file
> unreadable by some "export grade" software.  By default, the private key is
> encrypted using triple DES and *the certificate using 40-bit RC2.*

So unless you use this option, the certificates are encrypted using RC2. You can change the algorithms for either key or certificate using the options `-keypbe` and `-certpbe`.

Also for `openssl pkcs12` the `-nodes` option is only listed in the section:

> The options for parsing a PKCS12 file are as follows:

But you are not parsing such a file, you are creating it and if you look at

> The options for PKCS12 file creation are as follows:

the option `-nodes` is not even listed.

Just hitting return when prompted for a password also won't mean "no password" but it means "empty password" (your password is an empty string), which is legal. The reason why this works like no password in some cases is that some software will try to read PKCS#12 files with an empty string password first and only if that fails, prompt the user for an actual password, so if the password is empty, the user won't ever be prompted in these cases making it look like there is "no password" set.

This can cause issues in macOS and iOS, as Apple assumes that PKCS#12 always has a password set and it won't allow you to enter an "empty password", so if a file has an empty password set, it's impossible to import it on these systems. Firefox also had this issue in the very beginning but [it was fixed 13 years ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265991).

When reading a PKCS#12 file, OpenSSL itself tries to distinguish "no password" and "empty password" only by guessing. Here is original code from the project:

```c
 /* If we enter empty password try no password first */
 if(!mpass[0] && PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, NULL, 0)) {
     /* If mac and crypto pass the same set it to NULL too */
     if(!twopass) cpass = NULL;
 } else if (!PKCS12_verify_mac(p12, mpass, -1)) {
     BIO_printf (bio_err, "Mac verify error: invalid password?\n");
     ERR_print_errors (bio_err);
     goto end;
 }
```

The first time `NULL` is passed for password, the second time the empty string is parsed for password. Now let's look at the code when creating a P12 file:

```c
 p12 = PKCS12_create(cpass, name, key, ucert, certs,
             key_pbe, cert_pbe, iter, -1, keytype);
```

Theoretically this call would create a PKCS#12 file without a password if `cpass` is `NULL`, however, when this call is being made, it cannot be `NULL` because if you follow the code path from the beginning of the function to the call above, there is no code path that would lead to `cpass` being `NULL` in the end.

```c
 if(!cpass) {
     if(export_cert) cpass = passout;
     else cpass = passin;
 }

 if(cpass) {
   mpass = cpass;
   noprompt = 1;
 } else {
   cpass = pass;
   mpass = macpass;
 }
```

In case `cpass` was still `NULL` at the last `if`, it will be set to `pass` and `pass` is:

```c
char pass[50], macpass[50];
```

This is a static variable and when stored to a pointer, this pointer cannot be `NULL`. There is no other code that ever assigns a different value to `cpass`, so `cpass` can be an empty string but it can certainly never be `NULL`.

The actual encryption happens at a function named `PKCS12_add_safe_ex()` and if look at this function, you see the following code:

```c
    if (nid_safe == 0)
#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_RC2
        nid_safe = NID_pbe_WithSHA1And3_Key_TripleDES_CBC;
#else
        nid_safe = NID_pbe_WithSHA1And40BitRC2_CBC;
#endif

    if (nid_safe == -1)
        p7 = PKCS12_pack_p7data(bags);
    else
        p7 = PKCS12_pack_p7encdata_ex(nid_safe, pass, -1, NULL, 0, iter, bags, ctx, propq);
    if (p7 == NULL)
        goto err;
```

`nid_safe` is a number that tells the function which encryption method to use. As you can see, if it isn't set (value of `0`) a default is used which is either RC2, or in case not available, 3DES.

However, if `nid_safe` is `-1`, which means `NONE`, an alternative function is being used and `pass` is not even passed to this function, so the value of `pass` is entirely irrelevant in that case. So you can provide any password you like, if you set the encryption algorithm for the key and the certificate to `NONE`, nothing is encrypted.

Comment: Mecki, it is possible to generate unencrypted PKCS12 file with just OpenSSL command line utility! Look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62863490/7878845 for details. Variable `cpass` passed to `PKCS12_create()` is ignored when both `key_pbe` and `cert_pbe` are set to `-1` which can be achieved by command line argument `NONE`.

Answer (score 29):

To generate unencrypted PKCS12 file with just OpenSSL command line utility, call following command:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE -nomaciter -passout pass: -out bundle.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile ca-cert.crt
```

When encryption algorithm for private key (`-keypbe`) and certificate (`-certpbe`) is set to `NONE` then openssl's pkcs12 library ignores password argument and does not encrypt private key and certificate.

This can be verified by `openssl pkcs12 -info` command:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -in bundle.pfx -noout -passin pass:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 1
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Data
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Key bag
```

Please note that when reading existing PKCS12 file with openssl command line tool, it is needed to specify `-passin pass:` argument even when data are not encrypted. This is because openssl command line tools cannot detect if PKCS12 file is encrypted or not. When empty password is specified then openssl first tries to read file as unencrypted. And if it fails then openssl tries to read that file as encrypted with empty password.

When I generate `bundle.pfx` without specifying `-keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE -nomaciter` arguments then `openssl pkcs12 -info` shows following:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -info -in bundle.pfx -noout -passin pass:
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
```

So data are in this case encrypted with empty password.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue when needed to convert certificate for `openconnect`

Needed additional step to make it without password

```sh
openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.nopwd.key
```