# openssl pcks12 generate certifaciate need export password

Tags: openssl, export

I have encountered a problem when I was trying to generate certificate using the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey client.pem -in client.cert.pem -name "client" -certfile ca.cert.pem -caname "VPN CA"  -out client.cert.p12
```

the output：

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey client.pem -in client.cert.pem -name "client" -certfile ca.cert.pem -caname "VPN CA"  -out client.cert.p12
Enter Export Password:
```

but, what is the export password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a PKCS#12 file without an export password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497723/export-a-pkcs12-file-without-an-export-password)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the password blank if you will. 
The password (it can be empty) is needed to extract the key from the .p12 container.

Answer (score 0):

The PKCS #12 format seems to require a password for encrypting the included private key when you are exporting the private key and certificate into a file.

So the tool asks you to tell it the password it should to encrypt (not decrypt) the private key inside the export file.

So you need to make up that password yourself or use a password generator to generate a randome one. It's *not* a password which you are expected to already know.