# Convert vault PKI issued certificate to PFX format to be stored in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, openssl, pki, pfx

We have an internal Vault PKI used to generate certificates for Linux and windows machines. 
   For windows I'm using this [package](https://github.com/zyborg/Zyborg.Vault) to communicate with the vault API

```
   <# ...
    code to deal with the authentication with the vault PKI
    ... #>
   # generate a certificate 
   $hostname=hostname
   $certData=Write-VltData "pki_int/issue/$hostname" -Data @{ ttl="1440h"; common_name=$hostname; }
```

[image: the content of the issued certificate]

To store this certificate I need to convert it to .pfx format, so I have the following:

```
$data.certificate | out-file "c:\certs\server.crt" -Encoding "UTF8" -force
$data.private_key | out-file "c:\certs\server.key" -Encoding "UTF8" -force
```

and I've installed **openssl** to convert the certificate and the private key to **pfx**  format

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out C:\certs\server.pfx -inkey C:\certs\server.key -in C:\certs\server.crt -passout pass:
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\certs\server.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

but the last cmdlet throws me this error:
[image: the result of the cmdlet Import-PfxCertificate]

I also tried to manually import the certificate but I got the following window which prompts for password, even if I didn't specify any pass during the conversion.

[image: mmc.exe]

My question at last(I know you've been waiting too), how to successfully import the PFX certificate ?
**N.B:**

- I'm working on a **windows** machine **2016**
- The powershell version is **5.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry for not updating this questions, got other stuff in the middle.
So after struggling with this for hours, we found out that the version of windows I was using [**windows 2016 server which the OS build was less than 1703**](https://github.com/dsccommunity/CertificateDsc/issues/153) doesn't support importing pfx certificates generated by **AES256-SHA256** encryption so we changed it to **TripleDES-SHA1** at exporting time **AND** setting the algorithm to SHA1 which wasn't set by default by the openssl command, so the following command did the trick for us:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -macalg SHA1
```

this command will prompt for password that will be used later to export the pfx certificate to the windows store, if you don't want to have any password you can add this argument to the above command `-passout pass:`

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Vault, you really want PKCS12 keystore without a password.

Specifying `-passout pass:` is not enough, you need all of these:

```
-keypbe NONE -certpbe NONE -nomaciter -nodes -passout pass:
```

Details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62863490/591064

Comment: in my case this didn't work, I had to add ```-macalg SHA1``` even if in the doc they said it was set by default.