# NodeJs and HTTPS : how to use the "CSR" and "PEM" datas from globalSign

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a nodeJs http servers (Windows), created with the standard https.createServer method. I want to use a certificate I bougth from GlobalSign. They gave me a "csr" and a "pem". I saved them in a text file and tried to use them :

      `this.fHttpServer=https.createServer({
        key: 'csrFileFromGlobalSign',
        cert: 'pemFileFromGlobalSign'
      });`

But it gives me an "execution error" in nodeJs : "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

- I tried switching the files, same problem
- If I try with files generated by openSSL it works (no error)

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right, the key and the cert must be extracted from the pem file using [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516936/5936901). Later set key.pem to key, cert.pem to cert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could extract the "cert" file but I couldn't extra the "key" file, I tried <code>openssl rsa -outform der -in file.pem -out file.key</code>, but openSsl generates an error

Comment: You need the 'nocerts' option to output a key. 'openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pem -nocerts -out key.pem'